# Python - Gerar uma nova planilha de ocorrência de espécies por ano

Tags: python, pandas

[Imagem da planilha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtMot.png)

Tenho uma planilha de dados no Python com ocorrência de espécies e vários anos (1700 a 2019).

Gostaria de gerar uma nova planilha (DataFrame) a partir desses dados, essa nova planilha terá em uma coluna todas as espécies, uma linha com todos os anos e o número de ocorrência de cada espécie naquele determinado ano.

Por exemplo: a espécie X apareceu 5 vezes em 2010, a Espécie Y 15 vezes em 2011 (tabela abaixo)

Já tentei esse código e tive esse resultado:
`# especieis existentes data['ESPECIE'].unique()`

`array(['Eumops', 'Streptaxis', 'Haemulon aurolineatum', 'Tylosurus acus', 'Lutjanus synagris', 'Myripristis jacobus', 'Lutjanus jocu', 'Centropomus undecimalis', 'Notarius')`

Peço desculpas pela elaboração da pergunta.

| Espécies | 2010 | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 5 | 15 |
| Y | 0 | 0 |
| Z | 0 | 2 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta realizar o seguinte.

```
df['valor'] = 1  #Criar uma coluna com o valor padrão de 1

df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='values', index=['especies'],
                    columns=['ano'], aggfunc={'values': np.sum},fill_value=0)
```

DF inicial [Imagem DF Inicial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESxTJ.png) 
DF Ajustado [Imagem DF Ajustado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeX2k.png) 
Desta forma você terá o retorno desejado. 
Espero que isso resolva sua dúvida.

Comment: Agradeço! Consegui resolver com o link: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe). Exatamente com pivot_table